# How to make all EditText uneditable (and vicer-versa)?

Tags: android

I have an app where there are several text fields. I want to be able to toggle between editing them and not editing them. How can this be done without hard-coding the id for each and everyone one of the `EditText`?

For example, I'd like an alternative to

```
EditText Et = findViewById((R.id.one));
Et.setFocusable(false);
Et.setClickable(false);
Et = findViewById((R.id.two));
Et.setFocusable(false);
Et.setClickable(false);
//...continue the pattern
Et = findViewById((R.id.ten));
```

Comment: any feedback after the answers below?

Comment: yes, yours doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them in an array:

```
EditText[] etArray = { findViewById(R.id.one), findViewById(R.id.two), findViewById(R.id.three) };

for (EditText et : etArray) {
    et.setFocusable(false);
    et.setClickable(false);
}
```

or if the names are like EditText1, EditText2,.. for 10 views:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        int id = getResources().getIdentifier("EditText" + i, "id", getPackageName());
        EditText et = findViewById(id);
        et.setFocusable(false);
        et.setClickable(false);
    }
```

or even better, create an ArrayList in `onCreate()` and use the list:  
this declaration goes global in your activity

```
ArrayList<EditText> etArrayList;
```

this is for onCreate():

```
etArrayList = new  ArrayList<EditText>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    int id = getResources().getIdentifier("EditText" + i, "id", getPackageName());
    EditText et = findViewById(id);
    etArrayList.add(et);
}
```

and use this anywhere in your activity class:

```
for (EditText et : etArrayList) {
    et.setFocusable(false);
    et.setClickable(false);
}
```

Comment: Is this the best? No way to iterate over them without knowing the name?

Comment: Yes there is but you will have to change their names to something like EditText1, EditText2,... I will edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to modify your EditTexts without hardcoding stuff. Suppose they're included in a `LinearLayout` named `main_content`, then you can loop through each of them in the following way:

```
LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.main_content);
for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
       View widget = layout.getChildAt(i);
       if (widget instanceof EditText) {
           widget.setFocusable(false);
           widget.setClickable(false);
       }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. The `if` statment is never true and I think it's because the `EditText` is inside a `TableRow`

Comment: so use `TableRow layout = findViewById(R.id.tableRowID);` TableRow is a LinearLayout therefore you can loop through child views.

Comment: unfortunately the `EditText` are in multiple `TableRow`s

Comment: I still believe that the loop can be made considering the parent view that contains all the TableRow

Comment: When I do the `TableRow layout = findViewById(R.id.tableRow1);` then it works for the EditTexts in just the first row.